# convert string to an array using JQuery

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var string = "Chemistry,English,History";
```

***Sir i want to convert it to an array like:***

```
var subjects= ["Chemistry","English","History"];
```

**using jQuery**

Comment: Use `split`. `string.split(",")`

Comment: Please in future, try to articulate a proper question and don't just copy + paste one sentence into title and text.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular *[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* Do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: There's no jquery here.

Comment: should we remove the tag?

Answer (score 2):

No need of jquery. Just use .split() function to achieve this.

```js
let string = 'Chemistry,English,History';
let arr = string.split(',');
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: i got it .Thanks

Comment: welcome Muzzamil. Do accept the answer if this has helped you. :)